# Select random Leads records using SOQL (Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce, apex

I created an Auto Number type field (Lead Id), which by default is stored as string in Salesforce.

From "Lead Id" field, I created formula number field "Formula Lead Id" which should be a number without decimal.

My plan was to use this number to randomly select Leads using SOQL e.g. :

`SELECT Id, Name FROM Lead WHERE IsConverted = false AND Formula_Lead_Id__c > randomNumber LIMIT 5`

This does not work at all returned Leads do not have "Formula Lead Id" number close to randomNumber.
I know there are leads that are much close or even match randomNumber.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, since the [`ORDER BY`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) clause is missing, if `randomNumber` is 10 and you have 100 leads (`Formula_Lead_Id__c` from 1 to 100) that SQOL may return any 5 leads in the range 11-100, so it may return lead89, lead90, lead91, ..., lead98.

Try to change the SOQL to:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Lead
WHERE IsConverted = false AND Formula_Lead_Id__c > :randomNumber
ORDER BY Formula_Lead_Id__c
LIMIT 5
```

Please note that using `ORDER BY`, the default order is ascending, that's why I didn't wrote `ORDER BY Formula_Lead_Id__c ASC`.
Moreover there is no need to inlcude the `Id` explicitly if the SOQL contains any other field.

Now, since the `ORDER BY` clause is set, if `randomNumber` is 10 and you have 100 leads (`Formula_Lead_Id__c` from 1 to 100) that SQOL will return the leads from 11 to 20.

If you need also the one with a `Formula_Lead_Id__c` that match `randomNumber` you should use `>=` operator

```
SELECT Name
FROM Lead
WHERE IsConverted = false AND Formula_Lead_Id__c >= :randomNumber
ORDER BY Formula_Lead_Id__c
LIMIT 5
```